# Segmentation fault on Vuejs client - Debian Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, debian, vue.js, vuejs2

Im working on a Vue App. I develop it on Windows and it works fine - no errors. But when I copy my project (except of the node modules) to my Debian server, install all dependencies and start it I get this error: `Segmentation fault`.
I found the error is based in the `src` folder. If I copy any file from there (except the assets folder / files) the `Segmentation fault` error appears but not if I copy my modified config and build files.

ps. When I copy my project to a new folder on Windows and install the dependencies it works and the Vue Client server is running.
And if I create a new vue client project on my Debian server and let it run it also works ... till the moment I copy my `src` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I downgraded Node from 6.10 to 6.9.5
To use an older version is often the solution.

source (german): https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/segmentation-fault-error-beim-vuejs-client---debian-server?foundIn=login&randomReloadId=981505#comment-151824131